# How do I automatically verify my contracts on etherscan using brownie?

Tags: brownie

I discovered truffle has `truffle-plugin-verify` that help you verify your contracts on etherscan. I wonder if similar functionality can be done with brownie ?

Comment: If they have a Github, file an issue and post the answer here when you get it too.

Answer (score 0):

In your deploy call after calling {"from": account}, add publish_source=True

Example:

```
def deploy():
   account = accounts[0]
   Contract.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source = True)
```

When you check etherscan it will show that your contract was verified